# Project & css hosted on GITHUB is not rendering on mobile device

Tags: css, github, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I open https://bomengeduld.github.io/debadkamers/ on my mobile device, half of the project is not rendering. Only headr & first section is showing. Second section not. It looks completily blanc. It does renders perfect on desktop.

**What I have tried so far**

1) I have added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

2) I tried to add css to `<style>`  tag in `<head>`

3) The css is held in seperate file, and I already tried to add it to the style.css file.
https://github.com/bomengeduld/debadkamers/blob/master/css/responsive.css

It should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not referring to the css folder change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

Comment: Hi Taz, thanks for looking into this but 1) style.css is kept in rootdirectory or project folder and not in css folder 2) header is rendered properly 3) stylesheet css for mobile is spelled correctly. So what else could it be? Did you checked it on your phone?

Comment: @GinoJanLudikhuyze Im only getting errors with style.css https://i.imgur.com/xUacmqr.png and responsive.css is loading just fine for me https://i.imgur.com/HEGW9Ou.png. This is what your site looks like for me https://i.imgur.com/nLGKpyX.png, make sure that all your css files are linked right and that your media queries are correct.

Comment: on desktop its working fine https://bomengeduld.github.io/debadkamers/ so i dont get it

Comment: please have a look at my rootdirectory and you understand that all is connected well. I basicly used a existing template, where the style.css file was kept orginal. I only did some styling.

Comment: And I am sure style.css will render just fine, I was doing something while you were looking.

Comment: This appears to be working fine with no issue on mobile. Perhaps @TazTheManiac was correct in what they suggested would fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @rawnewdlz thanks for looking into this. 

For me it just doesnt work. All works fine on desktop, but when I open on my HUAWEI, only my header section shows up, & service.section remains blanco.

Can you describe if the service sections shows as the example above? And please have a look at the rootdirectory. The answer given is not the solution. I have tried it.

Comment: @GinoJanLudikhuyze I can't find any issues with the site, neither on mobile or desktop. Is your phone caching the site?

Comment: Like I said, only the header section with parallax background & text (html + css) is showing... But service section remain complete blanco..


I use android, I never had any caching issues. And not sure how to check that either. At least thanks a lot so far!

Comment: Holy Crap: Problem Solved! Apparently the link i used was not caching the website properly. thanks for the help!